# Sql Server: Count and group Marks by Student

Tags: sql-server

I have a this Table;

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>StudentID</th><th>AcademicYear</th><th>Term</th><th>StudentName</th><th>Class</th><th>Marks</th><th>Position</th><th>Count</th></tr><tr><td>12013</td><td>2015</td><td>One</td><td>Adamu A. Msangi</td><td>Form IV</td><td>80</td><td>1</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>52013</td><td>2015</td><td>One</td><td>Angela M. Lucas</td><td>Form IV</td><td>67</td><td>2</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>22014</td><td>2014</td><td>Two</td><td>Agness Daudi Martin</td><td>Form II</td><td>60</td><td>3</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>32014</td><td>2014</td><td>Two</td><td>Agness John Missana</td><td>Form II</td><td>51</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>42013</td><td>2015</td><td>One</td><td>Andrea F. Agustino</td><td>Form IV</td><td>50</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Which I got by running this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS Position,  
    COUNT(StudentID) OVER() AS 'Count'
FROM 
    Student
```

The output I'm looking for should show the student Position and Total number of Students. For example if I Query Student with ID No; 42013 and Term='One' and AcademicYear=2015 and Class='Form IV', I should get results similar with the following table:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>StudentID</th><th>AcademicYear</th><th>Term</th><th>StudentName</th><th>Class</th><th>Marks</th><th>Position</th><th>Count</th></tr><tr><td>42013</td><td>2015</td><td>One</td><td>Andrea F. Agustino</td><td>Form IV</td><td>50</td><td>5</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is what I tried with no success;

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS Position,  
    COUNT(StudentID) OVER() AS 'Count'
FROM 
    Student 
WHERE 
    StudentID = 42013 
    AND Term = 'One' 
    AND AcademicYear = 2015 
    AND Class = 'Form IV'
```

How can this be done??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your query in a subquery and then filter it:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (
            partition by term, class, academicyear
            order by Marks desc
            ) as Position, count(StudentID) over (partition by term, class, academicyear) as Student_count
    from Student t
    ) t
where StudentID = 42013
    and Term = 'One'
    and AcademicYear = 2015
    and Class = 'Form IV'
```

Comment: Thanks @GurV for a quick reply , Is there a way to get correct number of students per term, class , AcademicYear for the Target/respective Student.For example the above query should show 3 students in the Student_count column.. Thanks again

Comment: @Sandet I think you want `partition by`. Updated my answer. Can you try and let me know if it helped?